# What is an intuitive explanation for the exponential form in the Arrhenius equation?

Tags: kinetics

What is an intuitive explanation for the exponential form $\exp(-\Delta E/(kT))$ in the Arrhenius equation?

While I know the reaction rate theory, I am puzzled by the origins of the form of the equation, esp. the exponential form. Please give references if any.

Comment: Are you familiar with [this calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_beta#Statistical_interpretation) in statistical mechanics? One intuition is that the reactant state forms at a rate proportional to its energy-implied probability.

Answer (score 3):

As said by [M. Farooq](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/66245/m-farooq) in the comments, *The Origin and Status of the Arrhenius Equation<sup>[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed059p279)</sup>* clearly describes the method by which Arrhenius came with the Arrhenius equation. An excerpt from the article:

> Arrhenius considered eight sets of published data on the effect of temperature on reaction rates and showed (using  more currently conventional symbols) that in each case he  could choose a value of the constant $C$ such that $k$($T_1$, the  rate constant at a temperature $T_1$, was represented adequately  by the equation,
> $$k(T_1)=k(T_0)\mathrm{exp}\left[C\left(T_1-T_0\right)/T_1T_0\right]\tag 1$$
> where $T_1$ and $T_0$ are the temperature in Kelvin. This was  tantamount to showing that the rate constant could be represented as an explicit function of temperature, namely:
> $$k(T)=A\mathrm{exp}(C/T)\tag 2 \label{eqn:2}$$
> where $A = k(T_0)\mathrm{exp}(C/T_0)$ and both $A$ and $C$ are constants  for the particular reaction.
> The reactions which provided these eight sets of data are  listed in the table, along with the respective equations put  forward by each author to inter-relate rate constant and  temperature, where $T$ refers to the Kelvin and $\theta$ to the Celsius  scale and $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants.
> $$
> \textbf{The Data Considered by Arrhenius}\\
> \begin{array}{cccc}
> \hline
> \text{Author} & \text{Reaction} & \text{Temperature range/°C} & \text{Author's Equation}\\
> \hline
> \text{Hood (1885)} & \text{Oxidation of }\ce{Fe}\text{ II by }\ce{ClIO3-} & 10-32 & k=a.b^\theta \\ 
> \text{Warder (1881)} & \text{Alkaline hydrolysis of }\ce{EtOAc} & 4-38 & (a+k)(b-\theta)=c \\
> \text{Urech (1884)} &  \text{Inversion of sucrose} & 1-40 & . . . \\
> \text{Spohr (1888)} & \text{Inversion of sucrose} & 25-55 & . . . \\
> \text{Hecht and Conrad (1889)} & \text{Reaction of ethoxide with MeI} & 0-30 & k = a{10}^{b\theta} \\
> \text{van't Hoff (1884)} & \text{Decomposition of aqueous chloracetic acid} & 80-130 & \log_{10}k = \frac{a}{T} + b \\ 
> \text{van't Hoff (1884)} & \text{Decomposition of chloracetate ion in alkaline solution} & 70-130 & \log_{10}k = a\theta - b \\
> \text{van't Hoff (1884)} & \text{Dehydrobromination of dibromosuccinic acid} & 15-101 & \log_{10}k = a\theta - b \\
> \end{array}
> $$
> ... This leads to the logarithm of the rate constant being a linear function of temperature, which was the relationship used by van't Hoff in respect of two reactions. Thus, Arrhenius was the first to assert that eqn. $(\ref{eqn:2})$ was generally applicable to all reactions, and the equation is justly named after him, although he did not originate the relationship.

---

**Reference:**

<sup>([1](https://doi.org/10.1021/ed059p279))   Logan, S. R. The Origin and Status of the Arrhenius Equation. *J. Chem. Educ.* **1982**, *59* (4), *279*.</sup>